# Is html5 useful in animating vector graphics?

Tags: javascript, flash, html, vector

Does html5 help developers animate vector graphics in any way? I'm talking about straight key-frame vector animation, such as what flash does.

Is the way to do this basically using javascript to manipulate SVG graphics (such as what http://www.raphaeljs.com does? which is a bit weird to me since it's been supported in browsers for quite some time) or does html5/canvas lend itself someway to vector graphics animation?

I'm just trying to understand what's the "new" way developers will animate vectors on the web if/when flash plug-in eventually dies.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There's also [CSS animation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-animations/), which is declarative and can be more efficient because the JavaScript code is not pushing the animation.

But there's nothing inherently wrong with the SVG approach and it's more compatible as well.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no alternative for complex animations like the animations you can create with Flash (eg. shape-tweens or animations with 3d or bones), and I personally I think Flash is the way to go if you want crossbrowser killer animation. The Flash IDE offers lots of animation features which are not implemented in any other current web based tool. HTML/css is very limited, since it does not fully support skew/rotation/perspective in all browsers and in HTML you cannot animate background images too. However you can create programmatic tweens (like motion-tweens) with Javascript. At this state of HTML you must be a bit hardcore programmer to get a serious DHTML animation and I think you have to deal with CSS sprites or other blitting techniques to get some performance. Beside animation, Flash offers filtering and blendmodes too, which you would like to use in great animations too.

You can use the animate() function from jQuery for very simple animations (move, fade, slide); you can change properties over time. For a lot of web applications; this could enough. But if you want to animate vectors or want frame based animations; Flash is currently the best choice.

PS. What is wrong with animated GIF's?

Comment: Your knowledge is not up to date. It's possible to do a lot of the things you call impossible with the HTML5 family of technologies.

Comment: I did not meant impossible, I meant not supported or well-implemented (which is a shame); Yeah it works in your browser, but HTML5 is not fully supported yet. Yes, you can use some beta features from browsers (with -moz or -webkit prefixes) but it is not accepted and standardized yet (when we talk about animations) The current state of HTML5 is not ready and usable for real life, when you care about cross browser implementations. Please tell me which part of my answer isn't right. Complex animation is not a part of HTML, you should Flash nowadays.

Comment: +1, flash can at least be useful as an environment for creating and developing animations. Such thing just doesn't exist for html

Comment: -1 b/c my question wasn't answered. my question was about the future not right now. also i want to do vector animations not use jquery to move things around or animated gifs.

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryZP00_KhYE) might be interesting in the future. It is a flash to Html5 conversion tool form Adobe. Maybe there is a future on the web where the two technologies converge to a single purpose in stead of being two concurrent technologies side by side.

We may well agree that flash has some drawbacks, closed, slow technology. But I can not believe there is no knowledge in the flash source code, its developers and the large amount of users that could be helpful in the development of Html5. Flash is an easy to use environment for creating animations. Such an environment just does not exist for Html 5. So I believe there is room for flash and Html 5 together.

**Edit**

You should check out [Adobe Edge Preview](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/edge/). a new tool from Adobe for creating rich HTML5 animations.

Comment: i saw this before, i guess my question was what makes this tick... i'll have to delve deeper into what this exporter does to find out. +1

Comment: Check out new tool Adobe Edge